# Estimate Shipping Country Only?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-address, estimate

Just wondering if it is possible to change the 'Estimate Shipping and Tax' function in the cart to only show the Country. We plan on doing flat rate shipping based on countries, so for the estimate function, so we only need the Country drop down..

In the latest Magento version (1.9.x) is there a quick and easy way to disable/remove the 'State/Province' and 'Zip/Postal Code' options in the Shipping Estimator?

I can't disable them completely however as they are needed in the customer details when purchases are actually made...

Anyone got any idea's that might point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest option is probably to copy `app/design/frontend/base/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml` to your own theme and simply comment them out the 2 fields.

Comment: Cheers for the clarification, that was my thought but I was not sure if that would have had adverse effect on anything else - I am only new to Magento so still learning what breaks what.. :P

Thanks :)

Comment: As @DanHanly points out, you'll need to make sure Postcode isn't required, but from that point there shouldn't be any adverse affect, I've removed them in the past.

Comment: I found  the section required (for me) it was app/design/frontend/default/*mytheme*/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml. But your info steered me in the correct direction thanks. :)

Comment: Note that the javascript that adds the "required-entry" class to the postcode field is also within this file so you should comment that out too.

Comment: Shipping cost estimation working on cart page but not working on the checkout page, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 'Post Code Optional for Countries' in the backend of the site under System > Configuration > General

This will stop it being 'Required'. From this point, you can remove the field from the template as @Cags suggested.

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it out... From the sounds this allows the estimate to continue without the info that will essentially only be hidden from view (but still there) using the above method.

Just thought I would check first in case there was some obscurely hidden option in the admin backend that just untick and it hid the extra options or something.

Thanks :)

Comment: I found having no required states and setting 'display not required states' to No, got rid of the state field for me. Just a shame the same option is not available for the postcode...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan and Cags for the assistance working out the answer.

I found having no required states and setting 'display not required states' to No, got rid of the state field completely for me.

It's just a shame the same option is not available for the postcode...

Your info steered me in the right direction to find the section required, for me it was ***app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml***

I did find removing/commenting out the postcode section completely did stop the 'Get A Quote' button working, so I just added ***style="display: none;"*** to both the **label field** for postcode and the ***div class="input-box"*** for the postcode.

At this stage that appears to be working as required.